# ECONNRESET error while fetching an URL in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, dom, fetch

Getting the below error when trying to fetch (***using npm node-fetch***) html from the link below:

> Failed to fetch page:  { FetchError: request to
>   https://www1.nseindia.com/marketinfo/companyTracker/compInfo.jsp?symbol=TCS&series=EQ
>   failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
>       at ClientRequest

I am using the following snippet :

```
const DomParser = require("dom-parser");
const parser = new DomParser();
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

router.get("/info", (req, res, next) => {
  var url =
    "https://www1.nseindia.com/marketinfo/companyTracker/compInfo.jsp?symbol=TCS&series=EQ";
  fetch(url)
    .then(function(response) {
      // When the page is loaded convert it to text
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(function(html) {
      // Initialize the DOM parser

      // Parse the text
      var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");

      // You can now even select part of that html as you would in the regular DOM
      // Example:
      // var docArticle = doc.querySelector('article').innerHTML;

      console.log(doc);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("Failed to fetch page: ", err);
    });
});
```

The response was consoled log few times before showing the error and now its throwing err everytime I call /info.

I have tried the snippet in repl online editor. it returns `Promise {pending}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use some modern promise based packages to do this job. some are `got`, `axios` etc. `node-fetch` was last published 8 months ago. It might not be able to handle the encoding or compressing.

here is an example using `axios` which works.

```
const axios = require("axios");
const DomParser = require("dom-parser");
const parser = new DomParser();

var url =
  "https://www1.nseindia.com/marketinfo/companyTracker/compInfo.jsp?symbol=TCS&series=EQ";
axios(url)
  .then(response => response.data)
  .then(html => {
    // Initialize the DOM parser

    // Parse the text
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");

    // You can now even select part of that html as you would in the regular DOM
    // Example:
    // var docArticle = doc.querySelector('article').innerHTML;

    console.log(doc);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log("Failed to fetch page: ", err);
  });
```

Answer (score -5):

As far as I know you cannot use `fetch` in NodeJS. You need to rely in different methods. I personally usually use Axios.

Check also if this part of the code actually returns a promise:

```
return response.text()
```

Before chaining another `.then`.

https://www.valentinog.com/blog/http-js/

Comment: Actually .text() is a jQuery method, how are you using this in the back-end?

Comment: With ref to [link](https://javascript.info/fetch)- response.text() returns promise.
I am using npm [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) for using fetch.

Comment: Oh ok I see! This makes a difference, please add it in your question! :)

Comment: in fact, it was working initially. but now i get this error